# nvm use does not switch node versions

Tags: nvm

on a Windows 10 machine and using [nvm4w](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) I tried:

[image]

from the above image:

- `node --version` to check the current version
- `nvm list` to list installed versions
- `nvm use 8.8.1` so we switch from 6 to 8
- `nvm on` to enable it
- `node --version` to re-check the node version

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check you have installed nodejs separately. Just uninstall nodejs from control panel it will start working

Answer (score 309, accepted):

I had to delete the folder located at `C:\Program Files\nodejs`:

[image]

And then run `nvm use {version}` again to repopulate this folder with the correct node version.

I suspect that nvm is having trouble deleting this folder due to permission issues.

Comment: `nvm alias default {version}` for linux

Comment: that's exactly the case, I just ran the powershell as **Administrator**  then reused nvm and it worked !

Comment: I have the same problem, when I enter the NVM USE but I am prompt with 2 exit status 1 error, and when I delete this one I am only prompt with one. I also read the same question from Github turns out there is a problem if there is a white space.

Comment: on Mac you can use `which node` command to locate and delete the node coming not from nvm

Comment: respect tried thousands of thing finally found this solution.....thanks

Comment: "I suspect that nvm is having trouble deleting this folder due to permission issues." <-- That is correct.  "c:\program files" folder won't always be editable by other than an Administrator. So, when you run "nvm use x.x.x" command, as a non-administrator role, you won't always get expected results. You can either run that command, or delete/rename the folder, but it will need to be as an administrator.

Comment: I can't even find that folder under Program Files, I fixed my environment variables but couldn't locate this one! what to do?

Comment: This definitely has worked for me many times in the past! Is there any solution to preventing this from happening again? This seems to happen everything month or so normally around the time I update my computer.

Answer (score 67):

So I found a workaround.

I renamed `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to `C:\Program Files\nodejsx`

and then running `nvm use versionNumber` works fine.

Seems like nvm cannot change it to a symlink and fails **silently**.

Comment: Effect answer, rename it and change version it will work.

Comment: renaming it means nvm will create a new folder at C:\Program Files\nodejs. To avoid confusion, get rid of the folder cause it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 21):

I was also facing the same issue.

I had node version `14.15.1` installed in my machine and had to use `12.16.1`

I'm using **Windows 10**.

After installing `12.16.1` via nvm it was showing only this version in `nvm list` and it wasn't showing current version in use.

Even after `node use 12.16.1` the `node -v` was still showing `14.15.1`.

Steps to resolve this issue:

- **Uninstall** Nodejs from control panel.
- **Install** Nodejs 12.16.1 using `nvm install 12.16.1`
- **Install** Nodejs 14.15.1 using `nvm install 14.15.1` *(or the version which got uninstalled)*
- **Switch version** using `nvm use 12.16.1` *(change the version number accordingly)*

Result:

```
C:\>nvm list

    14.15.1
  * 12.16.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    12.3.1

C:\>node -v
v12.16.1
```

Comment: the question has some years, so I've evolved since  - if you install [nvm through chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/nvm), all works out of the box... since I started to use Chocolatey, I have no issues with anything, even upgrading software is easy, and when there's the software you don't want to upgrade, you can pin them and they will never be upgraded 

Comment: So what are you trying to do with these steps? "Installing, uninstalling, installing" does not make much sense to me lol; also note: I also use choco, powershell admin to install/use. never worked.

Comment: This worked. The problem for Windows are conflicts between the various node.js/nvm/yarn...

Answer (score 17):

For me the problem (on Linux) was that I had installed node with Homebrew, and it was preventing the use of nvm. Before nvm could set up the correct symlink, I had to

```
brew uninstall node
```

I first found out about this situation by running

```
which node
```

This told me that node was being symlinked from Homebrew at

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/node
```

instead of, as we want, from nvm at

```
/home/john/.nvm/versions...
```

As soon as "which node" reported that it was using the node from nvm, things were resolved for me.

Comment: My problem wasn't with nvm or brew eventually, the node version was coming from volta. But running which node as said here helped me find it quick and install right version with volta.

Answer (score 11):

nvm works based on the fundamental idea of `symlinks`. When a user is trying to hit the command `nvm install <node_version>` the entered version of node is getting installed even if you have changed the `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to `C:\Program Files\nodejsx`.

If nvm fails to create the new folder `C:\Program Files\nodejs` it will fail silently and you won't be informed.

You must manually check for the existence of the path `C:\Program Files\nodejs` if it exits then delete the folder and change the node path in your environmental variables. This will help you to figure out the version of the npm command.

Comment: and if nvm is not creating the folder nodejs ?? what should I do ?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem can be solved by reinstalling the nvm version with Administrator privileges or just by renaming the folder C:\Program Files\nodejs

You can find further information here: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/67

Answer (score 5):

I have tried to switch Node version using nvm but it is not reflecting so I  deleted the folder inside c:/program files/nodejs
[image]
after deleting the folder follow the same steps to switch the npm version using nvm and it will switch the node version.

Comment: This is very similar to the top answer. Can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 4):

1) Install NVM from the link : https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases.

2) Copy the settings.txt from the "C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\nvm". to "C:\Users\ YOUR_USERNAME"
3) Restart your system for the changes to reflect.
4) Open the console and type below command :
         nvm list
5) To install the 6.9.3 version run the below command :
         nvm install 6.9.3
6) After the installation is complete it will add the node version in the nvm. To check the same type command :
         nvm list
7) To switch the command version type command below command :
         nvm use 6.9.3
         To verify the node version switch type the command “node –v”
8) Its will display the node version in use.

For more details please check the below link :
https://www.tutespace.com/2018/11/nvm-installation-on-windows.html

Let us know if you still face the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled nodejs via chocolatey (the way I installed it) and then nvm worked again.

After checking the nodejs folder in C:/Program Files I noticed that nvm probably works via creating a link/shortcut to the nvm folder where the different versions of nodejs are stored. That's the way the path and everything works.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to be the issue till date and deleting nodejs folder does not work.

Just run nvm install  using `cmd as administrator`.

So even if you have downloaded nodejs from cmd without admin privilages, uninstall it and install again using cmd as admin.

This is what worked for me after trying almost every solution from github and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another answer because none of the others helped me.

## Setup

- Windows 11
- Multiple accounts
- Non-default install and symlink directories

I installed nvm using different directories than the default because this is necessary to avoid:

- Issues due to spaces in the path
- Issues when using nvm on two different accounts on the same machine

## Solution

This solution works for any number of accounts on the same machine.

1. Uninstall any nvm and nodejs you have.
2. Make sure no directory from them remains (in Program Files, Program Files (x86) and any other place you might have tried installing nvm/nodejs)
3. Reinstall nvm with:

   - An installation path that contains no spaces, and is not in any specific user's directory (e.g. `C:\nvm`)
   - A symlink path that contains no spaces, is not in any specific user's directory, *and is not under nvm's directory* (e.g. `C:\nodejs`)
4. Open your shell *as administrator*, install your desired node version(s) (e.g. `nvm install lts`) and activate one (e.g. `nvm use 18`)
5. Test that the version was activated correctly with `nvm current` and `node --version`
6. *Every time* you change your node version with `nvm use` or install a new one with `nvm install`, do it in an administrator shell

Answer (score 2):

The steps I had to follow were:

1. Uninstall node if there was an installation outside of nvm
2. Ensure "C:\Program Files\nodejs" was deleted before installing nvm
3. Install nvm which still fails to install node but from the errors it seems that's because its ultimately pointing at urls that have been decomissioned
4. Use "nvm install NODE_VERSION" to install at least 2 versions of node which again fail as in 3)
5. Download the versions of node I tried to install and unzip the entire contents to their respective %appdata%/nvm/vNode_version folders
6. Use "nvm use NODE_VERSION" to switch between either version I've installed [but be careful... "npm -v" did not work until in visual studio until I closed and re-opened the program]

If anyone knows how to point nvm to the up to date urls, it'd be great to know. I suspect everything would work fine when running nvm from powershell run as administrator

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step

1.delete node and npm in  path

To Find Path

```
which node
```

**output**

/c/Users/balaji/AppData/Roaming/npm/node

```
which npm
```

**output**

/c/program files/node.js

2.To list out version

```
nvm list
```

3.set node

```
nvm use version
```

To know remote version

```
nvm  list available
```

To know local version

```
nvm list
```

Comment: which is not a powershell command...

Answer (score 1):

On Windows uninstalling Node.js at `Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a program`, and letting nvm install the desired node versions also solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the things didn't work as described inside CI/CD service (TeamCity to be exact). I spent half a day, trying to find a solution and tried *everything* mentioned here and other similar questions. So, what worked:

1. Perform a clean install of nvm (removing older standalone versions of nodejs fist), as specified by multiple other answers. Install node versions only using **nvm**.
2. Make sure that process that is running your "**nvm use**" command has "Full Control" privilege to the root of nvm installation. So that it could delete the symbolic link "**nodejs**" folder when switching versions.
3. Change a policy on your server to allow that same account creating symbolic links:
   [image]
   This point was, somehow, not mentioned by anyone anywhere, so it took me very long time to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted nodejs folder from C drive and it work fine

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall node if you installed it using windows installer, then install it using nvm again.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above helped in my case.
I could see the symlink was created and correct but NVM4W would still not "use" the correct version.
The node version I had installed with NVM was not compatible with my version of Windows.

When you run "nvm ls" or "nvm current", it calls GetCurrentVersion() which runs "node -v" in the command line.  If that output is anything other than the current version, such as the warning that you are running an incompatible OS, it will fail to indicate the currently selected version.  It does so in a way that is not obvious why "nvm use x" did not work.

You can bypass the node OS check with an environment variable (node version >=14 as far as I could find):
[How to set the NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK environment variable to 1 which skips the version check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738844/how-to-set-the-node-skip-platform-check-environment-variable-to-1-which-skips-th)
Though you may need to update Windows or use an earlier version of node if node doesn't function as expected.

With that set, "nvm use" functioned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem this morning. And I think the reason for the problem is that it's different between the nvm's settings and env configuration. I solved it the following way.

1. open the path of nvm installation.
2. open the setting.txt file and have a check with the path value.
3. open the environment variables Control panel in Windows.
4. check if it's the same between the value of `NVM_SYMLINK` in the system path and `path` in the setting.txt
5. change two configuration to same values.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was caused by EMSDK. which I set on my .zshrc to load it automatically. removed the emsdk related lines, and the node was following nvm.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Windows 10.
I **reinstalled nvm**. and opened Command Prompt but after I wrote `nvm use version` it didn't work. then I **closed and reopened Command Prompt**. It was working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I realized I had forgotten to turn the NVM on, I turned it on and it started to work.

```
nvm on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm), it would block `nvm use`. Just use `fnm use` for instead.

Comment: and "If" you would look at the dates, you would see this question was asked in 2017, where `fnm` is only available [since 2019](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm/releases/tag/v1.0.0) 

Answer (score -1):

I was also having the issue where `nvm use` would say it was using the version I asked it to switch to, but then `node -v` said nothing changed. For me, `which node` brought two paths back, which was weird, because the base paths were the same. My home directory is `/Users/stephene`

```
which -a node
/Users/stephene/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.5/bin/node
~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/bin/node
```

In `~/.bash_profile`, I had

```
export NVM_DIR="~/.nvm"
```

I figured NVM was getting confused by the home file path reference, so I spelled it out for NVM by updating my .bash_profile

```
export NVM_DIR="/Users/stephene/.nvm"
```

and that fixed the problem.