# How to set the NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK environment variable to 1 which skips the version check

Tags: node.js

So earlier I was using node version **v13.6** bascially because I am on **windows 7** and node.js supports only windows 7 till v13.6 . So what I did was I downloaded the node.js latest version(v14.x.x) in **'.zip'** package and replaced all the files in the nodejs folder with the newer version file. I also know how to set environment variable but **how can I set NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK to 1** from the system properties in order to bypass the and run the latest version of node.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMLqu.jpg)?

Comment: Did you tried adding environment variable at the OS level and setting the value as one ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This work for me

1. Go to System-Properties (run: systempropertiesadvanced.exe), in
   Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
2. Still on the System variables, click 'New', add "NODE_PATH" with value "C:\nodejs64\node_modules", and click OK.
3. click 'New' again, add "NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK" with value "1", and click OK.
4. Click OK of all dialogs close.
5. Restart your machine, so explore and cmd will get the fresh set of variables.

Comment: Step 2 are 5 may not be needed, since the installation checks just the NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK variable. Instead of restarting the machine, you can just close the command prompt and re-open it.