# Can't switch to another version of Node

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nvm

I can't switch any more to another of Node versions I Installed via NVM.
So far I did it by using these commands:

```
nvm list //to check Node versions available on my machine
nvm use X.X.X //to pick a version
node -v //to check if I'm using the Node version I picked
```

Now If I run those commands I see that the current node version is always 14.17.0.  This is what Visual Studio Code terminal shows me:

```
$ nvm list
    14.0.0
    12.11.0
    12.2.0 
    12.0.0 
    11.11.0
    10.24.1
    8.16.2 


$ nvm use 12.0.0
Now using node v12.0.0 (64-bit)


$ node -v
v14.17.0
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017812/nvm-use-does-not-switch-node-versions)?

Comment: Thank you man. I looked on the Internet but I didn't find this thread.
This solution works :)